# How to access the URL of an image in CSS that Symfony2 Assetic dumped?

Tags: php, symfony

I am using basic CSS background images and I am running image filters that optimize the images in Symfony2. However, it seems that the URL of the compiled/processed CSS file contains wrong URLs:

```
url("../../Resources/public/images/gradients-1x210.png") repeat-x scroll 0 -66px transparent
```

I don't understand why it has transformed my URL from `../images/gradients-1x210.png` to that.

I have tried both `cssfilter` enabled and disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the relative path from /web of your image? Is it in web directory?

You can use absolute paths like /web/images/gradients-1x210.png

Comment: Paths are `web/css` and `web/images`, so the images reside relatively like `url(../foo.png)`.

Comment: ok. Try cssrewrite.
`{% stylesheets 'bundles/yourbundle/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}{% endstylesheets %}`
Then run assets:install, dump, and.. pray :)
Now Mr Symfony should know the correct relative path of your css and transform it rightly to your /web/bundles path. (I hope)

Comment: The problem was that I was using `{% stylesheets '@MyProjBundle/Resources/public/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}{% endstylesheets %}` instead of using `bundles/...` path. Assetic is broken with those `@` paths. However, installing the assets to the web folder all the time is painful, so I keep them under Resources, and I did `assets:install --symlink web` that symlinks it. It even works on Win 7 if under Administrator.